# What range of tcp buffer size do you suggest for slow and fast networks?

Tags: wi-fi, internet, mobile-network, gprs

If you search the net, you come across with ranges like these that claim would enhance your net throughput:

```
net.tcp.buffersize.default=4096,87380,256960,4096, 16384,256960
net.tcp.buffersize.wifi=4096,87380,256960,4096,163 84,256960
net.tcp.buffersize.umts=4096,87380,256960,4096,163 84,256960
net.tcp.buffersize.gprs=4096,87380,256960,4096,163 84,256960
net.tcp.buffersize.edge=4096,87380,256960,4096,163 84,256960
```

In place that I live, the net speed of gprs/edge connectivity is so slow that even sending just a sentence of text via instant messaging apps like Whatsapp could take up to 5 seconds and even fails to send some times! but on the other hand my wifi connectivity is very fast;

so; what range of tcp net buffer size do you recommend for these two connections that better suits me?(or maybe any other effective variable)

Comment: Is there a reason to believe that the smart Android engineers did not choose the "best" values for the buffersize? I'm usually skeptic about recommendations "from the net", and I doubt that your issues will improve when you modify the buffersize, because I don't think they are related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bufferbloat only becomes a problem when the link (i.e. your edge/gprs connection) is congested. If it's not congested, you may just have very poor cellular reception.

If bufferbloat is really the reason you will be unable to do anything locally (because the problem is very probably the largish buffer size on the cellular network equipment).

A few pointers:

- try to avaid parallel traffic when using WhatsApp
- try to switch off Image loading in WhatsApp (not sure if this is possible as I don't use WA)
- (root required) use an outbound app firewall to avoid unnecessary traffic (e.g. [AFWall+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall))
- (root required): use an adblocker to avoid unnecessary traffic (e.g. [AdAway](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.adaway))